# How to compare values in a map with a threshold and put the values greater than the minimum threshold in a set

Tags: java

I have a map containing string keys and integer values, I am trying to compare the values to a threshold say 40  and print all the keys with a greater value than the threshold to a set. Here is my code and the error i am getting. I am new to java

```
    int m = 40;

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();


    System.out.println();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> i = set.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext() ) { 
        Map.Entry e = i.next(); 

    if(e.getValue() > m) { 
        set.add(e.getKey());
    }
    System.out.println("Set of local file names and malware score : "+ i.next()); 
    }
```

Error:

> ```
> no suitable method found for add(Object)
>                         set.add(e.getKey());
>                            ^
>     method Collection.add(Entry<String,Integer>) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,Integer>)
>     method Set.add(Entry<String,Integer>) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,Integer>)
> 2 errors
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add keys (of type `String`) to the entry `Set` (which contains elements of type `Map.Entry<String,Integer>`). That's the cause of the error.

However, even if the types were matching, you shouldn't modify the entry `Set` of the `Map` (unless you want to modify the underlying `Map` too).

You should create a separate `Set` to store the relevant keys:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

System.out.println();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (i.hasNext() ) { 
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> e = i.next(); 

    if(e.getValue() > m) { 
        set.add(e.getKey());
    }
}
```

I removed your `println` statement from the loop, since it was advancing the `Iterator` a second time in the same iteration, which is wrong.